# Is it possible to get function's signature from a library?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld, nm

Let's suppose nm reports a function symbol in the library utils:

```
$ nm --defined-only utils.so
T function_symbol
```

Is it possible to determine the signature of that function (return type and parameters)? Or at least the number of parameters and the size of each parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to obtain this information from DWARF debugging information. But if the debugging information is unavailable (either because it has been stripped or was not generated during compilation in the first place), this is not possible.  An ELF object does not contain this information.

For C++ function symbols, the mangling shows the type of the function arguments, but even there, the type of the function result is missing, so the picture is still incomplete.

Comment: Thank you. Even the number of parameters is unavailable?

Comment: Yes, the number of parameters is not available either.

Comment: By the way, how linker determines whether the library resolves the undefined symbol then? Does the linker match undefined symbol and defined symbol without the knowledge of their types??

Comment: Yes, there is no type checking for function symbols. (For C++, there is name mangling, of course, but that is not something the linker needs to be aware of.)